# Question on logarithm with variable base

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

The question is $4.7=x^.25$
At first I tried to write it in log form: $\log_x4.7=.25$
Then I realized I can just raise the original equation to the fourth power. But, going with my initial approach, how would I finish the problem? 
Is there a calculator that can solve a log with a variable in the base?
Thanks,
Aaron

Comment: Do you know what $x^{.25}$ actually means? In particular, if you were to write it as $x^{1/4}$, could you work with that instead?

Comment: Or alternatively: If you take a natural logarithm, the statement is just that $\ln(4.7) = 0.25 \ln(x)$, from which you can find $\ln(x)$ and hence $x$.

Comment: Kind of circular.  The only way to solve $\log_x a = b$ is to solve $x^b = a$.  Which is simply $x = a^{1/b}$.

Comment: I don't know of a calculator that does that but a program can be written that solves it.  But it'd be considered equivalent to solving $x = a^{1/b}$ so why bother.

Comment: The problem would have been different if $4.7=x^{0.251}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realize that $$\log_{x}\frac{47}{10}=\frac{1}{4}$$
This implies that $$\log_{\frac{47}{10}}x=4$$
Because $$\log_{a}b \times \log_{b}a=1$$
So we have that $$x=\left(\frac{47}{10}\right)^4$$
So you can see using logarithims provides the same result, albeit in a more roundabout way. Also, to answer your second question, most CASIO calculators and Wolframalpha can solve a log with a variable in the base.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot, this was the explanation I was looking for.

Comment: @AaronM Thanks, but do realize that the other answers are correct as well. Using logarithms, as I said, is a more roundabout way, and as fleablood said, needlessly complicating matters. I suspect you already realize this, but I am just making sure. If you found my answer helpful, I would appreciate if you would upvote or accept my answer.

Comment: Yeah I tried to upvote it, but it says I need a minimum of a 15 reputation(I have an 11 reputation). Thanks for your help though.

Comment: @AaronM have you tried clicking on the check mark?

Answer (score 1):

Logarithms are not required to solve this problem. Look at the position of the $x$ in your problem. It is raised to a power hence this should be solved similar to other power problems you have encountered such as: $x^3=8$. You would not solve $x^3=8$ using logarithms so you shouldn't for your problem either.

$$x^{0.25}=4.7$$

$$x=4.7^\frac{1}{0.25}$$

$$x=4.7^4$$

Contrast this to a problem where you have have to use logarithms such as $2^x=32$. In this problem the $x$ is in the exponent position. The difference here in the placement of the $x$ in the question is what tells you what technique to use in solving the problem.

Comment: The OP seemed to know this, but was curious about how one can continue if using logarithms.

Comment: Yes S.C.B, but thanks Ian for your explanation anyways.

Answer (score 1):

You want to isolate the $x$.  Putting $x$ in $\log_x$ does nothing to isolate $x$ and gets you no closer.  (It's stepping sideways really... and making an average problem hard.)

To isolate the $x$ is $x^{.25} = 4.7$ you must eliminate the power.  And to do that is to take it to the inverse power.

$x^{.25} = 4.7$

$(x^{.25})^{1/.25} = 4.7^{1/.25}$

$x = 4.7^{\frac 1{\frac{1}{4}}} = 4.7^4$.